# Search and get value from JSON dictionary in python

Tags: python, json

I have JSON data, need to get GUID value of name or shortname of input argument.

> Input : Script.py NAME or SHORT NAME
>
> Output: 49d01ed7-4285-4bed-a602-0e3bbdc179a1

Im new to python and JSON parsing. Any help or suggestion will be helpfull

```
       {
            "countries": [],
            "companies": [
                {
                    "guid": "49d01ed7-4285-4bed-a602-0e3bbdc179a1",
                    "custom_id": null,
                    "name": "Creavath, Sweaine & Mare LTD",
                    "shortname": "Creavath",
                    "href": "https://api.com/ratings/v1/companies/49d01ed7-4285-4bed-a602-0e3bbdc179a1"
}
                {
                    "guid": "edade1ed-9e08-4bc0-bc24-5d05c7903c53",
                    "custom_id": null,
                    "name": "Kremar Levin Natlis & Franklin LTD",
                    "shortname": "Kremar Levin",
                    "href": "https://api.com/ratings/v1/companies/edade1ed-9e08-4bc0-bc24-5d05c7903c53"
                }
]
}
```

Comment: What are you using in python to retrieve the JSON input? Since there isn't much context I don't know how to help you more than that

Comment: What you posted is not valid JSON. And please edit the question to include the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this-

```
import json
json_data = """{
            "countries": [],
            "companies": [
                {
                    "guid": "49d01ed7-4285-4bed-a602-0e3bbdc179a1",
                    "custom_id": null,
                    "name": "Creavath, Sweaine & Mare LTD",
                    "shortname": "Creavath",
                    "href": "https://api.com/ratings/v1/companies/49d01ed7-4285-4bed-a602-0e3bbdc179a1"
                },
                {
                    "guid": "edade1ed-9e08-4bc0-bc24-5d05c7903c53",
                    "custom_id": null,
                    "name": "Kremar Levin Natlis & Franklin LTD",
                    "shortname": "Kremar Levin",
                    "href": "https://api.com/ratings/v1/companies/edade1ed-9e08-4bc0-bc24-5d05c7903c53"
                }
            ]
       }"""
parsed_json = json.loads(json_data)
```

If you have json in a json file (with extension as .json), use this--

```
with open('jsonfile.json', 'r') as f:
    parsed_json = json.load(f)
```

After this, use the code below to get the guid for name or short name-

```
user_input = 'Creavath' # for example, user gives this input

for company in parsed_json['companies']:
    if company['name'] == user_input or company['shortname'] == user_input:
        print(company['guid'])
        break
```